# Fcron. Параллельное выполнение скриптов.

Tags: cron, unix, php, linux

Добрый день, товарищи.

Суть дела: Крон запускается раз в 10 минут, утилита (демон): **fcron**, заместо **cron**.

У **fcron** есть одна специфика, которая не позволяет выполнять задание, если предыдущее еще не выполнилось.

Например, скрипт **scriptname.php** выполняется по крону раз в 10 минут. И очередной раз запустился в 12:10. Но, если указанный скрипт не успеет выполнится за 10 минут, то в 12:20 следующий раз скрипт уже не запустится просто потому, что предыдущий еще не  выполнился (Прошу вашей профессиональной помощи!

**Мне нужна бесперебойная работа скрипта. Мне нужно, чтобы каждые 10 минут скрипт гарантировано стартовал, несмотря на то, что предыдущий еще не выполнился.**

Comment: а чем вас обычный crond не устроил?

Comment: Я пользуюсь тем что есть, изменить это, увы, я не могу ( Приходится пользоваться тем, что есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так это... В баше же можно любую команду (и скрипт в том числе) запихнуть в бэкграунд, поставив после неё значок амперсанда - "&". Вот тут очень хорошо описано, правда, по-аглицки: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2012-01/msg00063.html И хоть с десяток их в fcrontab засунь - вот они и форки!

Answer (score 0):

Первое что приходит в голову...

```
root@host:~# cat cron_dummy.sh#!/bin/bashwhile true; #Тут всякие там php /path/to/script > /dev/nulldo echo "good";sleep 600;doneroot@host:~# ./cron_dummy.sh &; disown
```